# Debug Guacamole auth hmac Java locally

Tags: java, python, django, debugging, pycharm

I have created a program using the Guacamole API (0.9.10-incubating). When running locally, I can debug the python using Pycharm debugging, but I want to debug the Java portion of Guacamole, the guacamole-auth-hmac authentication Java. Is there a way to debug Java in a django/python program? I have Intellij IDEA but so far can't figure out a way to debug the Java section on the localhost:8000.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the Guacamole remote desktop tool? That's the tag you used, but I don't understand how it fits in here. And how does Java factor in? Do you maybe mean Java_Script_?

Comment: Hi chris! Yes, I am talking about that Guacamole, I am using 0.9.10-incubating. The authentication in Guacamole uses Java (not Javascript) and I'd like to debug this section of the code.

Comment: Guacamole logs all messages by default. Do you see anything in logs?

Comment: Yes I can view the logs, but I would like to run the program in a debugger so I can set breakpoints to modify the authentication features

Comment: Wow that was a great question, i wish more people would answer it